# How to get html content of email template from Mailchimp then change it and send?

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am already following above one.

I will create one template with the variables that can be replaced.

Like First Name. Last Name.

So is there any API available to change those email templates before sending emails?

In Mailchimp we are **NOT** able get content of Email Template.

```
https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/templates/{email_template_id}/default-content
```

But, we are able to get content of Campaign.

```
https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/{campaign_id}/content
```

In **Mandrill** able to find

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.php.html#method=info -> To get the template info/content

Then we can update in and send via https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html#method=send

Why it is not possible in MailChimp E-mail template?